# Generating summaries automatically

Tags: excel, report, reporting, excel-formula, excel-2010

Part of my job is to pull a report weekly that lists patching information for around 75000 PCs.  I have to filter some erroneous data, based on certain criteria, and then summarize this data myself and update it in a separate spreadsheet.  I am comfortable with pivot tables / formulas, but it ends up taking a good couple of hours.

Is there a way to import data from a CSV file into a template that already has in place my formulas/settings, etc. if the data has the same columns, but a different amount of rows each time?

Comment: Open the CSV in excel, then copy and paste into your formatted spreadsheet...would this not work for you?

Answer (score 0):

If you're confortable with programming, then, you can use macros, on this case, you will connect to your CSV file, then extract the information and put it in the corresponding places on your spreadsheet, on this question you can find most of what you need to start off: [macro to Import csv file into an excel non active worksheet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14633691/macro-to-import-csv-file-into-an-excel-non-active-worksheet).