# Get data from website screen to Excel with form - VBA

Tags: vba, excel

With help from Stackoverflow, I reached to the following code; it basically opens IE, navigate to the url, fills the form and submit.

```
Sub getdata()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    IE.Visible = True
    IE.Navigate "http://www.bseindia.com/markets/equity/EQReports/BulknBlockDeals.aspx?expandable=7"

    Application.StatusBar = "Submitting"
    ' Wait while IE loading...
    While IE.Busy
        DoEvents
    Wend
    ' **********************************************************************
    delay 5
    IE.document.getElementbyid("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_chkAllMarket").Click
    delay 5
    IE.document.getElementbyid("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_txtDate").Value = "01/01/2014"
    delay 5
    IE.document.getElementbyid("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_txtToDate").Value = "12/01/2014"
    delay 5
    IE.document.getElementbyid("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_btnSubmit").Click
    delay 5
    '''IE.document.getElementbyid("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_btnDownload").Click
    '''(Commented as the click gives the option asking to save, open the csv file)

    '**********************************************************************
    Application.StatusBar = "Form Submitted"
    'IE.Quit            'will uncomment line once working
    'Set IE = Nothing   'will uncomment line once working

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub

Private Sub delay(seconds As Long)
    Dim endTime As Date
    endTime = DateAdd("s", seconds, Now())
    Do While Now() < endTime
        DoEvents
    Loop
End Sub
```

The Problem:

Once the form is submitted, the data gets populated on screen as well as there is an Excel icon (Download) with the same data in csv.

How can I get this data (anyone way is fine) in my active worksheet.

Comment: Is this <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14633691/macro-to-import-csv-file-into-an-excel-non-active-worksheet> along the lines of what you need to do now? Import the csv to a worksheet?

Comment: Thanks Jimmy, but since the website is PHP (I assume), the query table option doesn't work on it. In query table URL plays an important role in capturing data, however in my case URL doesn't change at all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this

```
Sub getdata()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    IE.Visible = True
    IE.Navigate "http://www.bseindia.com/markets/equity/EQReports/BulknBlockDeals.aspx?expandable=7"

    Application.StatusBar = "Submitting"
    ' Wait while IE loading...
    While IE.Busy
        DoEvents
    Wend
    ' **********************************************************************
    delay 5
    IE.document.getelementbyid("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_chkAllMarket").Click
    delay 5
    IE.document.getelementbyid("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_txtDate").Value = "01/01/2014"
    delay 5
    IE.document.getelementbyid("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_txtToDate").Value = "12/01/2014"
    delay 5
    IE.document.getelementbyid("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_btnSubmit").Click
    delay 5

    '**********************************************************************
    Application.StatusBar = "Form Submitted"

    Dim tbl As Object, tr As Object, trCol As Object, td As Object, tdCol As Object
    Dim row As Long
    Dim col As Long

    row = 1
    col = 1

    Set tbl = IE.document.getelementbyid("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_divData1").getElementsbytagname("Table")(0)
    Set trCol = tbl.getElementsbytagname("TR")

    For Each tr In trCol
        Set tdCol = tr.getElementsbytagname("TD")
        For Each td In tdCol
            Cells(row, col) = td.innertext
            col = col + 1
        Next
        col = 1
        row = row + 1
    Next


    IE.Quit            'will uncomment line once working
    Set IE = Nothing   'will uncomment line once working

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub

Private Sub delay(seconds As Long)
    Dim endTime As Date
    endTime = DateAdd("s", seconds, Now())
    Do While Now() < endTime
        DoEvents
    Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: +1: This is the best approach, as the table can be scraped consistently for any setting.

Comment: Excellent, Is there a way to stop IE pop (basically do all stuff in background), it is a bit annoying when doing in loops.

Comment: @Vasim Yes, there is better way of doing this.  I will prefer using xmlhttp instead of IE. Also then we won't have to assign textbox values one by one and wait for few seconds.

Comment: @Santosh, Thanks - I tried searching xmlhttp in Google, wasnt able to find any useful website, please can you lead me if you have any simple example.

Comment: @Vasim See [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17643483/trying-to-fetch-data-from-webpage-with-a-vba-code-but-sometimes-it-works-and-so/17666816#17666816)

Answer (score 0):

**Sorry misunderstand the question Initially.**

Now i got what OP wants.

Here I'm not going to tell how to click the open button in the download window.

But result will export the required data into excel(that's what OP want it seems)

**Tested and working fine in my system.**

```
Sub getdata()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    ie.Visible = True
    ie.Navigate "http://www.bseindia.com/markets/equity/EQReports/BulknBlockDeals.aspx?expandable=7"

    Application.StatusBar = "Submitting"
    ' Wait while IE loading...
    While ie.Busy
        DoEvents
    Wend
    ' **********************************************************************
    delay 5
    ie.document.getelementbyid("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_chkAllMarket").Click
    delay 5
    ie.document.getelementbyid("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_txtDate").Value = "01/01/2014"
    delay 5
    ie.document.getelementbyid("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_txtToDate").Value = "12/01/2014"
    delay 5
    ie.document.getelementbyid("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_btnSubmit").Click
    delay 5
   ' ie.document.getelementbyid("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_btnDownload").Click

Set doc = ie.document

For Each d In doc.all.tags("table")

If InStr(d.innertext, "Client Name") > 0 Then

With d
        For x = 0 To .Rows.Length - 1
            For y = 0 To .Rows(x).Cells.Length - 1
                Sheets(1).Cells(x + 1, y + 1).Value = .Rows(x).Cells(y).innertext
            Next y
        Next x
    End With

End If

Next d
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub

Private Sub delay(seconds As Long)
    Dim endTime As Date
    endTime = DateAdd("s", seconds, Now())
    Do While Now() < endTime
        DoEvents
    Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Sathish, I already have your code in my question. Question is how do I get the data from the Excel Icon file in active worksheet.

Comment: OP already stated he knows this. His problem basically lies in fetching the CSV from beyond the click, I believe, since it asks him to save or open the file.

Comment: @BK201 .Now i have updated my code.that works fine in my system

Comment: Y still i'm getting downvote though i have modified my code as per OP needs :(