# How to save file from Webpage from Excel VBA?

Tags: internet-explorer, excel, save, excel-2007, vba

I am trying to export a file from IE, after selecting an item in dropdown by taking the Html ID and clicking the export option, but i am strucked while saving the file.
I am Selecting the option in the dropdown based on the value in an excel range.

Please help.
Below is the code I am trying.

```
Dim htm As Object
Dim IE As Object
Sub Website()

    Dim Doc As Object
    Set IE = CreateObject("internetexplorer.application")
    IE.Visible = True

    IE.navigate "http://**Link is confidential, sorry for not providing link**"

    Do While IE.readystate <> 4: DoEvents: Loop

    Set Doc = CreateObject("htmlfile")
    Set Doc = IE.document

        Set ref = Doc.getelementbyid("ReportViewerControl_ctl01_ctl05_ctl00")
        For x = 0 To ref.Options.Length - 1
            If ref.Options(x).Text = "Excel" Then
                ref.selectedIndex = x
                Set refclick = Doc.getelementbyid("ReportViewerControl_ctl01_ctl05_ctl01")
                refclick.Click
                Set refclick = Nothing
            End If
        Next
    Set IE = Nothing
End Sub
```

And the snap shot I am strucked here, and here i want to save the file.
[image: how to select Save]

Comment: See this [**Get data from website screen to Excel with form - VBA**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22353665/get-data-from-website-screen-to-excel-with-form-vba/22354302#22354302)

Comment: Hello Santosh, I am trying to export the report which has more than 1 web page.

Comment: Instead of exporting you may extract the data from screen as per example in the link.

Answer (score 2):

Add the following in your code:

```
Dim Report As Variant

Report = Application.GetSaveAsFilename("Attrition Report.xls", "Excel Files (*.xls), *.xls")
```

Answer (score 0):

I sent the keystrokes of the shortcut keys to click the save button in IE11.

Note: the code will not run as you expect if IE is not the active window on your machine so it won't work while in debug mode.

- Shortcut key:<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>
- VBA: `Application.SendKeys "%{S}"`