# How to CLICK on IE download dialog box i.e.(Open, Save, Save As...)

Tags: excel, internet-explorer, vba

I want to be able to click on Open, Save, Save As... In Internet Explorer via VBA.

I attached a pic of the download dialog box...

[image: download dialog box]

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22470630/how-to-save-file-from-webpage-from-excel-vba

Comment: perhaps this thread helps ... http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/67123-visual-basic-applications-save-file-website.html

Comment: That did not worked! I want to be able to click on "Open" to open the file that I'm trying to download form the site. I'm guessing this is an IE security feature....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an easy way by using the TAB key... I modified the code a little:

```
Application.SendKeys "{TAB 1}", True 'This will select the (OPEN) Tab
Application.SendKeys ("~")
```

Source: https://www.autoitscript.com/forum/topic/154472-ie-download-saveopen-dialog-how-to-access/

Answer (score 1):

I used the shortcut keys for these. Here they are for IE11.

Note: the code will not run as you expect if IE is not the active window on your machine so it won't work while in debug mode. All this is doing is the equivalent to pressing keys on the keyboard.

### Open

- Shortcut key:<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd>
- VBA: `Application.SendKeys "%{O}"`

### Save

- Shortcut key:<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>
- VBA: `Application.SendKeys "%{S}"`